# Multiple foreign key column match conditions inside "WHERE x.xxx IN"

Tags: sql, oracle

This question was hard to title.

Effectively, I'm trying to write a query to get file information from table "ste_file" that corresponds to all entries on a table "st_chemical". The chemical table has one direct match to the file table (idfile_primary), and two different "file collections" that it has foreign keys to (clfilecoll_other and clfilecoll_MSDS), and these foreign keys match to a file collection table "ste_filecoll", that in turn references multiple files in "ste_file", all through the column "idfile"

Most of the versions of the query I wrote never worked - they would just spin endlessly. I finally ended up with this:

```
SELECT
    c.idchemical,
    f.idfile as "id",
    f.szname as "name"
from ste_file f, st_chemical c
WHERE f.idfile IN (
        SELECT fc.idfile
        FROM ste_filecoll fc
        WHERE fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_msds
    )
UNION
SELECT
    c.idchemical,
    f.idfile as "id",
    f.szname as "name"
from ste_file f, st_chemical c
WHERE f.idfile IN (
        SELECT fc.idfile
        FROM ste_filecoll fc
        WHERE fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_other
)
UNION
    SELECT
        c.idchemical,
        f.idfile as "id",
        f.szname as "name"
    from ste_file f, st_chemical c
    WHERE f.idfile = c.idfile_primary;
```

This works, but feels incredibly sloppy - I'm probably doing a ton of table scans. Is there a cleaner way to do this? I tried many variations, such as where I did the UNION inside of the WHERE IN clause instead, or tried not to union at all, but all of them never returned anything at all, just ran endlessly. An example of a query that does NOT work:

```
SELECT
    c.idchemical,
    f.idfile as "id",
    f.szname as "name"
from ste_file f, st_chemical c
WHERE f.idfile IN (
        SELECT fc.idfile
        FROM ste_filecoll fc
        WHERE fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_msds
    UNION
        SELECT fc.idfile
        FROM ste_filecoll fc
        WHERE fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_other
);
```

This one just runs endlessly. Any suggestions or ideas to simplify this? I have a lot of queries similar to this one to write, and I think I'm missing some basic concept that covers this much more cleanly.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  On first glance, your problem looks like missing `JOIN` conditions.

Comment: I'm still a bit of amateur - never heard of not using commas in from clauses, they use them all the time here. I tried to google that, but no luck - any links to some explanations? They aren't opposed to optimizations around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on 12c or later, you might try this:

```
SELECT c.idchemical,
       f.idfile as "id",
       f.szname as "name"
FROM  ste_chemical c 
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT fc.idfile 
              FROM ste_filecoll fc 
              WHERE fc.clfilecol1 IN ( c.clfilecol1_msds, c.clfilecol1_other )
              UNION
              SELECT c.idfile_primary idfile FROM DUAL ) fc
INNER JOIN ste_file f ON f.idfile = fc.idfile;
```

I sometimes find `CROSS APPLY` helpful when I have unusual join conditions like this.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! Runs muuuuch faster too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a bit difficult without seeing the data model and data sample but how about this?

```
SELECT
    c.idchemical,
    f.idfile id,
    f.szname name
from ste_file f, st_chemical c
WHERE exists (
        SELECT null
        FROM ste_filecoll fc
        WHERE (
            (fc.idfile = f.idfile) and
            (fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_msds or fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_other)
        ) 
    ) 
or f.idfile = c.idfile_primary
```

May be it's intentionally but you are also missing the join between `ste_file f, st_chemical c`

Comment: Unfortunately, does the exact same thing - just runs endlessly. Something about using two comparisons in the line `(fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_msds or fc.clfilecoll = c.clfilecoll_other)` seems to do it, from my experimentation. One comparison is okay, but two makes it run forever.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how though - the two tables only directly relate through idfile_primary, but the other two columns only relate through ste_filecoll - then ste_file relates to ste_filecoll. Should I do two joins that way instead? I've not written many joins.

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the data model. But without a join between these two tables you will get to many records which will slow down your query.